# Neo4j match node for exact match a word with parenthesis in the field

Tags: regex, neo4j, cypher

I'm currently exploring Neo4j for a hobby project; I'm facing some problems in getting the exact match on a field when that field has parenthesis in it:

```
create (:Employee { name: "abcd", department: "Human Resources Recruitment" });

match(n:Employee) where n.department =~ '.*\\bHuman\\b.*' return n
```

This works but if a node has parenthesis for e.g:

```
create (:Employee { name: "abcd", department: "Human Resources (Recruitment)" });

match(n:Employee) where n.department =~ '.*\\bHuman\\b.*' return n
```

This does not return anything.

Can you please help me if I'm doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use `'.*Human.*'` as regex because it'a more clear and no need of word boundary here.

This will match both your cases as it doesn't only looks for `Human` followed and preceded by `nothing` or `many` characters.

And still if you wish to add word boundary, add it like this `'.*\\bHuman\\b.*'`

**Why your regex is not working?**

Well your regex `.*\bHuman.*\b` is checking for `word boundary` at the end of string. And your string `Human Resources (Recruitment)` is not matching it because last character `)` is left out after matching boundary just after `t`.

[Demo for left out )](https://regex101.com/r/fF3vD6/1)

[Demo to include everything](https://regex101.com/r/fF3vD6/2)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Actually I need to have a exact match test for more complicated cases. I'm actually ranking fetched records based on the matching cases and this exact match should be a separate case. the regex type you've suggested I want to use it for some other cases. Do you've any idea why it doesn't work with paranthesis ?

Comment: I think you should edit your question. Because `.*` is visible as `.`

Comment: @techkriti: I have found your problem and updated my answer.

Comment: note that in neo4j 2.3+ you can MATCH using CONTAINS (case-sensitive) :  `MATCH (n:Employee) WHERE n.department CONTAINS "Human" RETURN n`

Comment: @ChristopheWillemsen: Thanks for the addition. This will definitely help OP in refining search.

Comment: also in neo4j 3.x, CONTAINS is INDEX backed

Comment: @noob: Thank you very much. This solves my problem. I didn't realise that word boundary was not matched.